# How to get 10s, 100s, 1000s from an integer?

Tags: ruby

Is there a method in ruby that allows breaking integers up into 1s, 10s, 100s, 1000s, ...?

I know that you can convert an integer to a string and parse the string to get the values mentioned above, but I would imagine there is a really simple way to do this with ruby like most other things. So far I have this:

```
1234.to_s.chars.reverse.each_with_index
.map{|character, index| character.to_i * 10**index }
# => [4, 30, 200, 1000]
```

But is there something specific to do this in ruby?

Comment: Straight forward... create the method, and there you go.

Comment: Two things are making your question unnecessarily difficult: (1) the order is reversed, (2) the powers of 10 expressed are redundant. If you had asked for `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, then it would have been much easier.

Comment: So given input `1020`, the output would be `[0, 20, 0, 1000]`.  Is that really what you want for the hundreds place?

Comment: Yes. Not sure how this is unnecessarily difficult if those are my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that as follows:

```
n = 1020304

Math.log10(n).ceil.times.with_object([]) do |i,a|
  n, d = n.divmod(10)
  a << d * 10**i
end
  #=> [4, 0, 300, 0, 20000, 0, 1000000]
```

Hmmm. That looks a bit odd. Maybe it would be better to return a hash:

```
Math.log10(n).ceil.times.with_object({}) do |i,h|
  n, d = n.divmod(10)
  h[10**i] = d
end
  #=> {1=>4, 10=>0, 100=>3, 1000=>0, 10000=>2, 100000=>0, 1000000=>1}
```

Comment: My initial reaction was to use log10, but I forgot to use ceil.  Nice solution Cary.  My solution also used a hash, but I removed it per the original questions example.  I would also prefer it in the other order, to reflect the left to right matching with reading the original number.

Comment: @vgoff, people (mostly oldtimers) keep telling me there is no order to a hash's key-value pairs. :-)

Comment: It was the order of the array that I was speaking of, not of the hash.  And of course, now Hashes do have a predictable order.

Answer (score 1):

```
def value_of_powers(number, base: 10)
  number.to_s.reverse.each_char.with_index.map do |character, index|
    base**index * character.to_i
  end.reverse
end

value_of_powers(10212, base: 3) # => [81, 0, 18, 3, 2]
value_of_powers(1234)           # => [1000, 200, 30, 4]
```

I reversed the order so that the values are read in the same order as we read numbers.

As shown, it also works for other base numbers.  Given no base, it will default to base 10.

Comment: Not limited to base 10.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly clever, but I suppose it's relatively clear about what it does.

```
def tens_places(n, place = 1)
  if n >= 1
    [(n % 10).floor * place] + tens_places(n/10, place * 10)
  else
    []
  end
end
```